# Perform an action daily at a specified time

Tags: ios

In my application I add income and expense data and display it in a home page as a summary. Now suppose I have some fixed expense, which happens daily, that will be automatically added to the expenses at the time which I set. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use timer or notification only when you are creating a reminder kind of feature.

As per my understanding from your question, I would suggest you following suggestion:

- Keep track of last time that the expense was added to your app's local database. You can store this information in database or in user defaults.
- On next run of the application, check last entry time and then calculate other entries that needs to be done. If it is daily, it will be the number of days since last entry.
- Add the required entries to your database to make your entries consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UILocalNotification` with `repeatInterval` property which  reschedule the notification with  calendar interval. I suggest to go through following apple iOS guideline.

[UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/fireDate)

Hope, this will help you..